# Generating Unique number through Cryptography

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am using `Visual Studio 2013`, `iis-8.5`, `.net 4.5.1`
In my project, i want to create `8 digit unique number` which should be separated by a `'hypen'` in the middle and with prefix `"MNOP-"`. The generated `8 digit` should inherit the `Cryptography class`.
My code

```
var bytes = new byte[4];
var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
rng.GetBytes(bytes);
int random = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0) % 100000000;
var data = "ABCD-" + random.ToString("####-####");
```

I created 10000 value by `'for loop'`, but some `'random variable'` return negative value
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing is a question, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: 8 digits and unique? Pick one.

Comment: var bytes = new byte[4];
                var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
                rng.GetBytes(bytes);
                int random = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0) % 100000000; I ceated 10000 values by for loop, but some number gives negative values.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things you can do:

1. generate a random value (decimal digit by decimal digit) and check if you created it before, then store it into a list of pre-generated numbers;
2. create a 400 to 800 MB table and *shuffle* it, then store it on disk and use an offset into the table;
3. create a key and use it for a cipher (a PRP) that uses the exact same output as the input, and use a counter, basically implementing Format Preserving Encryption.

You should not just use a random number generator as the chance of collisions quickly increases with the amount of numbers generated. This is because of the Birthday problem.

This also means that solution 1) is not fit if you want to generate *a lot of* numbers, as it may stall. Imagine that you've got only one available number left, you'd have a 400 MB table and it is trying for that one 4 byte entry that's left. The other options require you to store a table and an offset or a key and an counter respectively.

---

Your current generation method is unbalanced as it generates lower numbers more easily than positive numbers. Furthermore, you should reset the most significant bit because `ToInt32` returns the *signed, two complement value*, and `%` is the *remainder* operator, not the modulus operator.

---

OK, for this time only, some C# code, to celebrate my bronze badge for the platform:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    class RandomIDGenerator
    {
        private const string FORMAT = "ABCD-####-####";
        private const string TEST_FORMAT = "ABCD-###";


        private RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        private byte[] b = new byte[1];
        private SortedSet<string> previousIDs = new SortedSet<string>();

        private char GenerateRandomDigit()
        {
            int x;
            do
            {
                rng.GetBytes(b);
                x = b[0] & 0xFF;
            } while (x >= 250);
            int y = x % 10;
            return (char) ('0' + y);
        }

        private String GenerateRandomID()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(TEST_FORMAT);
            for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sb[i] == '#')
                {
                    sb[i] = GenerateRandomDigit();
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public String GenerateUniqueRandomID()
        {
            string id;
            do
            {
                id = GenerateRandomID();
            }
            while (previousIDs.Contains(id));
            previousIDs.Add(id);
            return id;
        }

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            RandomIDGenerator gen = new RandomIDGenerator();
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(gen.GenerateUniqueRandomID());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Put breakpoint here...");

            foreach (string id in gen.previousIDs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(gen.previousIDs.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Put breakpoint here...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The strategy for (1) can be improved by always generating random numbers in the range of `0` to `max_number - already_generated_numbers` (I don't know if there is such a function in .net, but python has something like this) and then starting from 0 and only counting the unpicked numbers until one reaches the randomly generated index. Such a linear scan is costly, but it can be sped up considerably with a binary search tree.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Good one, forgot about it. 400 MB fits in memory and you would at least have a function that executes in somewhat predictable time.

Comment: can you give me a example